# Function not returning value correctly

Tags: php

I have a function that I am using for an experiment with a custom encryption method. The function should encrypt and return the value but instead returns nothing. Here is the function:

```
public function encrypt($value, $strlength){
    include('include/scripts/keys.php');
    global $Keys;   
    $output = preg_replace("/Password/", $Keys['Password'], $value);
    $output = preg_replace("/password/", $Keys['password'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/PASSWORD/", $Keys['password'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/a/", $Keys['a'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/b/", $Keys['b'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/c/", $Keys['c'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/d/", $Keys['d'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/e/", $Keys['e'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/f/", $Keys['f'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/g/", $Keys['g'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/h/", $Keys['h'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/i/", $Keys['i'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/j/", $Keys['j'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/k/", $Keys['k'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/l/", $Keys['l'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/m/", $Keys['m'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/n/", $Keys['n'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/o/", $Keys['o'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/p/", $Keys['p'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/q/", $Keys['q'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/r/", $Keys['r'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/s/", $Keys['s'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/t/", $Keys['t'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/u/", $Keys['u'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/v/", $Keys['v'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/w/", $Keys['w'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/x/", $Keys['x'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/y/", $Keys['y'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/z/", $Keys['z'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/1/", $Keys['1'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/2/", $Keys['2'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/3/", $Keys['3'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/4/", $Keys['4'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/5/", $Keys['5'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/6/", $Keys['6'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/7/", $Keys['7'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/8/", $Keys['8'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/9/", $Keys['9'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/0/", $Keys['0'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/_/", $Keys['_'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/-/", $Keys['-'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/A/", $Keys['a'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/B/", $Keys['b'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/C/", $Keys['c'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/D/", $Keys['d'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/E/", $Keys['e'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/F/", $Keys['f'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/G/", $Keys['g'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/H/", $Keys['h'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/I/", $Keys['i'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/J/", $Keys['j'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/K/", $Keys['k'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/L/", $Keys['l'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/M/", $Keys['m'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/N/", $Keys['n'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/O/", $Keys['o'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/P/", $Keys['p'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/Q/", $Keys['q'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/R/", $Keys['r'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/S/", $Keys['s'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/T/", $Keys['t'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/U/", $Keys['u'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/V/", $Keys['v'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/W/", $Keys['w'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/X/", $Keys['x'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/Y/", $Keys['y'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/Z/", $Keys['z'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/ /", $Keys[' '], $output);
    $output = substr($output, 0, $strlength);
    return $output;     
}
```

After changing each value it should return the output, but when I call it

`$encrypted = $this->encrypt($value, 40);`

and then

`echo $encrypted;`

Nothing is returned. No error, but no output.

**Edit:** The accepted answer below is correct, however, to explain better what I needed to do was include the keys outside of the class and set the global there, and then set the global in the class and it worked correctly. Thank you.

Comment: have you checked with echo $output inside the function ?

Comment: @GaneshKamath Yes, I just tried it, and no luck.

Comment: so basically, you function is not returning anything for the variable to collect. Push this function outside of the class, make it return the desired encryption value before pushing it back in.

Comment: can you check what "echo $value;" prints, from inside the function?

Comment: @GaneshKamath Can you elaborate for me please?

Comment: i am suspecting that $value is not being accepted inside the function. If "echo $value" prints the non-encrypted string, then we can conclude atleast that the input is reaching the function.

Comment: @GaneshKamath Yes, `echo $value;` prints the non-encrypted string correctly, so it's passing that.

Comment: Is the path of the included file correct? Try `print_r($Keys)` and see if it is displaying what it should.

Comment: If it is null, then it is possible that all the characters in your string are replaced by null, and hence the lack of any visible output.

Comment: @CEP Well, I know the file called keys is there, and I know it's accessible, and I know everything is defined, however, It's not outputting anything when I run `print_r`.

Comment: Try `require('include/scripts/keys.php')` instead of `include()` and see if it throws an error. If it does, and your path is correct, it is most likely a permission issue. In which case, you will have to `chmod` the `keys.php` file to make it accessible by the webserver and PHP.

Comment: No output still, but no errors thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function output length control.

```
//include('include/scripts/keys.php');
```

This include file array example

```
$Keys = array ('a' =>'a?2c7d', 'b' =>'b0*/&d', 'c' =>'c_d%e^f', 'Password'=> 'pass');
```

Example function

```
function encrypt($value, $strlength){
    global $Keys; 
    $output = preg_replace("/Password/", $Keys['Password'], $value);
    $output = preg_replace("/a/", $Keys['a'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/b/", $Keys['b'], $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/c/", $Keys['c'], $output);

        return substr($output, 0, $strlength);

}

 echo encrypt('abc abc', 40);
```

Return a?2c_d%e^f7db0*/&dc_d%e^f a?2c_d%e^f7db0

Sory, my English not good.